# Sencha Touch 2 PhoneGap issue for 4.0.x

Tags: android, cordova, caching, chromium

I have an Android HTC Amaze and an Android HTC Desire. My Sencha Touch 2 apps wrapped by PhoneGap work excellent for the Desire but they refuse to load on the HTC Amaze 4.0.3.
I'm getting this kind of errors in log -

> 08-24 17:08:37.577: E/chromium(16106): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:190: [0824/170837:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(190)] StatHub::Init - App "appname" isn't supported.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-252255.html?s=4cc94131e4b116bce59e89af85793aec

Answer (score 1):

Try to update cordova version as latest one.

```
cordova -v
npm install -g cordova
```

current recent cordova version is 8.x.
and please check which cordova plugins are installed.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap gives errors while compiling for production builds. Rather than PhoneGap use IONIC framework which under the hood run different libraries of PhoneGap but does not return such errors.

https://ionicframework.com/

If your application is in javascript use IONIC 1.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using WebView mecanism** in your app, try to change for [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/what-is-crosswalk.html).
In my case, **replacing** interaction with **android.webkit.WebView** with [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html) fixed the issue.

I don't really understand why, but Crosswalk is known for "*Uniform runtime across all devices and so you don't have to deal with runtime differences on different devices running different versions of the OS.* "

Answer (score -1):

Try updating your cloud build and re-install it on your Android 4.0.

Seems it needs to be re-installed for the new permissions to be noticed by the Android OS.